# How can I make my message <ul> element appear with jQuery when I post a message?

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<ul class="message" 
    style="border-width: 1px 0 0 0;
           border-top-left-radius: 0;
           border-top-right-radius: 0;">
</ul>
```

and this code that sets $message:

```
oLink.$message = oLink.$modal.find('.message');
```

I have the following javascript that adds a message:

```
obj.$message.html("<li>Contacting Server, please wait ...</li>");
```

This works but the problem is that when there is no message my ul is still styled with some properties that give it a height and make it show as an area at the bottom of my screen. Is there some way that I could make the  message invisible and then have it show up. I am not very good at jQuery but could I chain in a show or hide into when I am creating a new message?

Comment: Add `display:none` to the CSS and then use `.show()` in jQuery. Or did you have something more complicated in mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are the jQuery show and hide methods. If the message doesn't change anyway you could just insert it into the ul and then show/hide it like this:

```
$('.message').show();
$('.message').hide();
```

See for more info:
http://api.jquery.com/show/
http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Answer (score 1):

using css only (and modern browser) you can style an empty `ul` with `:empty` pseudoclass

```
ul:empty {
   display: none;
}
```

example fiddle : http://jsbin.com/ipeciw/1/edit

or just remove/hide programmatically the empty `ul` via jQuery with

```
$('ul:empty').remove(); // or hide() if you need it later
```

Comment: Only problem with this is that an empty ul is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

It's all css related. The height at you say is probably a default margin or padding.

You could hide it initially

```
ul.message { display:none; }
```

and then when you write the html, display it like so.

```
obj.$message..show().html("<li>Contacting Server, please wait ...</li>");
```